# What filter should i use to match the exact term/s inside a string?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 2.3.1.

I need to create a query that checks if specific term (a word or a list of words) are present in a text. Basically something as the **like** operator.

If i use the bool/must/match filter i can order the documents by score, but i must remove the documents that do not have all the terms i need to search.

At the moment i am using 2gram, this is the mapping...

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {             
                "2gramsto3_filter": {
                    "type":     "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 3
                }                
            },        
            "analyzer": {
                "2gramsto3": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter":   [
                        "lowercase",
                        "2gramsto3_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },  
    "mappings": {
        "agents": {
            "properties": {                             
                "cv": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "2gramsto3"                 
                }
        }
    }
}
```

but as i wrote above all the terms must be  inside the text so not just a bigram.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match by a specific set of words, then `bool/must/match_phrase` may be more appropriate than `bool/must/match`

A Quick reference about this can be found in the Getting started section of the documentation, which you can find here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_searches.html:

From the above source:

This example is a variant of match (match_phrase) that returns all accounts containing the phrase "mill lane" in the address:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": { "match_phrase": { "address": "mill lane" } }
}'
```

More details from ES documentation can be found at this location: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_searches.html

Comment: does it filter ALL the documents that have this exact term (or a list of words)? I mean.....does it is similar to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html? (but this works with not analyzed field)